# How does m2e detect which profile to use for build?

Tags: maven, m2e

I observe m2e picks up my desired profile for replacing properties during build.
Where does it get the profile from?
My parent pom has many profiles.
My profile is not present in activeProfiles section in settings.xml

All I do is right click on project and RUn as maven build.

Comment: post your effective pom `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: Also, you can get some hints by `mvn -X ...`

Answer (score 0):

Thre would be a file `org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs` located in `.settings` folder under your project. This file contains the m2e related preferences where you can even specify the `activeProfiles` which it would in turn use when performing a maven build.

The m2e picks up the active profile from this file.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse oxygen you can see this and choose which profile is using m2e by right clicking on your project / Maven / Select Maven Profiles ...

[image]